# How to make Leaflet Tooltip text selectable?

Tags: leaflet

How to make Leaflet's Tooltip (`L.tooltip`) text selectable with mouse? Setting `interactive` to `true` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

One of the differences between tooltips and popups is that tooltips do not respond to mouse events.

Text is selectable in popups.

A popup with `autoPan`, `closeButton`, `closeOnClick` and `autoClose` options set to `False` behaves almost like a tooltip.

Comment: The popup with settings you mentioned is what we use now as a workaround but it closes if user clicks on the marker.